# How to get the name of a method at runtime?

Tags: c#, methods, reflection

I'm using an event system that takes a string for the callback method name. I'd like to avoid hardcoding strings. Is there any way I can get the method names of given class in runtime?

Something similar to:

```
typeof(MyClass).Name;
```

but for methods would be perfect.

Edit:

I've been googling the problem and all results seem to be people looking to get the name of the current executing method. This isn't what I'm looking for - instead I'd like to get the name of other methods within the same class.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [CallerMemberName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: can you provide a sample code that you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're talking about the `nameof` operator, added in C# 6.0.

[MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn986596.aspx)

Excerpt:

> Used to obtain the simple (unqualified) string name of a variable, type, or member. When reporting errors in code, hooking up model-view-controller (MVC) links, firing property changed events, etc., you often want to capture the string name of a method. Using nameof helps keep your code valid when renaming definitions. Before you had to use string literals to refer to definitions, which is brittle when renaming code elements because tools do not know to check these string literals.
>
> A nameof expression has this form:

```
if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(x));
WriteLine(nameof(person.Address.ZipCode)); // prints "ZipCode”
```

Comment: just a note, its evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Thanks Smallhacker. Unfortunately I'm on 2.0, but this answer is definitely the most relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

Refer [MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx)

> Returns a MethodBase object representing the currently executing
>   method.

**EDIT:**

```
var str = typeof(MyClass);
MethodInfo[] info = str.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: I'm not using the current method. I'd like to use a different method.

Comment: You solution is right but I wonder if using current method's name will interfere in compiler optimization. Sometimes, compiler will get rid of single time used methods. I am not saying it's because of your solution, but in general if you try use current method's mane.

Comment: @Vesuvian, please make your question clear. What do you mean 'different method'? If you can already type the method name, just keep it in string if you are worried about 'other method'.

Answer (score 0):

For same method:

```
MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

For method in another class:

```
var type = typeof(MyClass);
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Then, you can use, for example, `methodInfos[0].Name` to get the name of the method.

If the method to be called is in the same class, you can do it as below:

**If it is method with no return type/void**

```
 Action action = () => { MethodToBePassed(); };

  public static void MethodToBePassed()
  {
  }

   public static void Test(string a, Action action)
   {
      action();
   }
```

Call it as below:

```
 Test("a", action);
```

**If method has return param**

```
 Func<string, int> action = (str) => { return MethodToBePassed(str); };

 public int MethodToBePassed(string sample)
 {
    return 1;
 }

 public static void Test(string a, Func<string, int> action)
 {
    int value = action("a");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems unreliable though. Now instead of making sure the string matches the method, I need to make sure the index matches the method position.

Comment: @Vesuvian Nope, dont rely on the index.The GetMethods method does not return methods in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which methods are returned, because that order varies.